# Can Injectable Services have a providers list?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I was doing some code with a component class and a service class.

```
@Injectable()
class MyService extends Object {
  ...
}

@Component(
  ...
  providers: const [MyService]
)
class myCompoment implements onInit {
  final MyService _service;
  MyComponent(this._service);
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to say, give a provider to my injectable service such that it can consume?  When looking online, it had shown that Component comes from Injectable, so I was thinking to create a component out of the service, but that doesnt quite make sense as to me a component would also have UI.

Ideally, I wanted to do something like:

```
@Injectable()
class AnotherClass {}

@Injectable(providers: const [AnotherClass])
class MyService extends Object {
  ...
}

@Component(
  ...
  providers: const [MyService]
)
class myCompoment implements onInit {
  final MyService _service;
  MyComponent(this._service);
  ...
}
```

but Injectable doesnt allow the providers property it seems.

Comment: I don't yet understand why you want to add providers to `@Injectable()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `providers: const [MyService, AnotherClass]` to components and `MyService` can inject `AnotherClass` by just listing it as constructor parameter

```
@Injectable()
class AnotherClass {}

@Injectable()
class MyService extends Object {
  final AnotherClass _anotherClass;

  MyService(this._anotherClass);
}

@Component(
  ...
  providers: const [MyService, AnotherClass]
)
class myCompoment implements onInit {
  final MyService _service;
  MyComponent(this._service);
  ...
}
```

Comment: that makes sense because myComponent has it has a provider and it walks up the call chain to find an instance to use.  If myComponent did not have it as a provider, I didnt think would work.  I figured you would have needed to add it to MyService somewhere?

Comment: Services are instantiated where they are provided. They have no hierarchy of their own. They follow the component hierarchy. Therefore adding providers at services doesn't make sense.

Comment: I guess you are right, I was trying to understand though what would happen if i say didnt have it provided.  Would that cause an error or would it implement its own instance as one did not exist? Id think it wouldnt as you didnt tell it that it is needed, right?

Comment: If Angular tries to create an instance of a component or service because a required constructor paramter can not be resolved (no provider found) an exception is thrown.

Comment: Makes sense.  Its just a runtime exception as it isnt something that would be determined through intellisense etc

Comment: That's currently not statically checked. It might be technically possible.